# How to write a mutation resolver that handles image AND form data upload stream?

Tags: express, graphql, aws-sdk, apollo, apollo-server

So, currently I’m able to successfully upload an image through the client to an S3 bucket. However, my question is, how would I go about including additional form fields, such as an accompanying title and/or body field, with the existing image file?

The server component primarily utilizes  `apollo-server-express`, `graphql-upload`, and  `aws-sdk`  while the client just uses `apollo-client`

My end goal is to essentially be able to take the user’s form data on submit that consists of multiple text fields and an image file, and then upload the contents to the s3 bucket in its own individual directory.

Would it be possible to compile the non-image-file form data as a json, and then upload both the files (the json and the image file) as a batch?

Here are some snippets for some context:

```js
// server/typedefs.js
const typeDefs = gql`
  scalar Upload
  type File {
    id: ID!
    filename: String!
    mimetype: String!
    encoding: String!
  }
    type Mutation {
    singleUploadStream(file: Upload!): File!
  }
  type Query {
    files: [File]
  }
`;
```

```js
// server/resolvers.js
...
...
Mutation: {
  singleUploadStream: async (parent, args) => {
    const file = await args.file;
    const { createReadStream, filename } = file;
    const fileStream = createReadStream();

    const uploadParams = {
      Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: `uploads/${filename}/${filename}`,
      Body: fileStream,
    };
    await s3.upload(uploadParams).promise();
    return file;
  },
}
...
...
```

```js
// server/index.js
...
...
const app = express();
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  uploads: false,
  introspection: true,
});
app.use(graphqlUploadExpress());
server.applyMiddleware({ app });
app.listen({ port: 4000 }, () => {
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`);
});
```

please don’t hesitate to ask if you need more info or if you’re not sure what I’m asking for!

I really appreciate any help I can get ☹️ Thank you!

---

My resources:

- https://www.apollographql.com/blog/graphql-file-uploads-with-react-hooks-typescript-amazon-s3-tutorial-ef39d21066a2/
- https://dev.to/fhpriamo/painless-graphql-file-uploads-with-apollo-server-to-amazon-s3-and-local-filesystem-1bn0
- https://www.thomasmaximini.com/upload-images-to-aws-s3-with-react-and-apollo-graphql

Comment: `uploads: false,` ?

Comment: did you ever solve this?